# Regex grouping one symbol and ignoring other occurrences of that symbol

Tags: java, regex, string

For a project I am working on, I have to parse a list of strings which are in the form

```
Comparing folder1name-folder2name: x
```

where x is a decimal value. I want to use a regex pattern and matcher to group each line into its individual elements so I can easily extract the folder names and the values (which I will use later).

I constructed the following pattern which works fine

```
        String pattern = "(Comparing )(.*)(-)(.*)(: )(\\d+\\.\\d+)";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pattern);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(data);
        while (m.find()){
            String f1 = m.group(2);
            String f2 = m.group(4);
            String value = m.group(6);
        }
```

The problem occurs when - occurs in the folder names, as the pattern can't tell where the folder name ends and the seperating - is.
e.g.

```
Comparing folder1-name-folder2-name: x
```

1. It's safe to assume that if a dash occurs in the folder names, there will always be an equal number of dashes in both names. Is there any way for a pattern to account for this possibility, and not mistake a - in a name for the separator?

Extra question about storing/reading very large string.

2. The string data I am using is being taken from a command line operation, and it may be extremely long, possibly exceeding hundreds of thousands of characters (depending on the amount of folders). Currently, I am taking the input stream from the process, converting it to a string builder, and then when it is constructed store it as a string which I can read.

   Is there a more efficient way to do this? Should I just read and parse it as the StringBuilder? I want to be able to read the data quickly, but am worried about storing so much in one String object. I don't want there to be a chance the string would be too large.

Thanks

Comment: I don't see any way of distinguishing a hyphen in a folder name from the hyphen that separates folder names.

Comment: I agree with @TimBiegeleisen here.. Even if some regex trick were to be used to get what you want, this approach would break in case the filenames change a little (or if hyphens were not balanced)

Comment: That's fair enough, I kind of suspected as much. That's no problem, I'll just include criteria for user input that no folders can contain hyphens in the name. Thanks for the help.

You wouldn't happen to have some advice for actually storing/reading the string, would you? I'm leaning towards splitting the builder into a String array of lines and just reading each one in a for loop.

Comment: Is there a reasonable limit to the number of dashes in each file name?

Comment: So far none of the test data I've been working with have had any dashes, but underscores instead. The folders all follow the same naming conventions, e.g. 000001_submission_file_. I just realized that, were there to be any dashes present, with my old pattern, it wouldn't parse it correctly.
So, to answer your question no, but the file names will at least be uniform and not too crazy (they all come from the same system).

Comment: Please post a few test cases that if they can all be matched properly you would have an answer (I have an idea of how to solve it, but I want to make sure I understand the problem)

Comment: @Bohemian for example, say the folders given to the program are  Student001_assign-file, Student002_assign-file, and Student003_assign-file. 
The output for the tool would be 
Comparing Student001_assign-file-Student002_assign-file: 80.5
Comparing Student001_assign-file-Student003_assign-file: 54.6
Comparing Student002_assign-file-Student003_assign-file: 58.6

The program would read each line and be able to group up the terms in the line to extract the folder names and the score. horcrux's answer below seems to work fine, as long as the dashes are balanced, which I will check for.

Comment: So is the maximum number of hyphens in any single file name 1? If not, what is the maximum?

Comment: Technically no maximum I guess, but unfortunately the program won't actually know until the input is passed into the program. For now, counting the number in each file name and splitting it so it knows how many to account for, as per horcrux's answer, works well enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First count hypen occurrences in the string (in the example i use `StringUtils`, but there are many ways), then use the half of this number to balance the 2 folders' names:

```
int count = StringUtils.countMatches(data, "-");
count /= 2;
String pattern = String.format("(Comparing )((?:.*-){%d}.*)(-)((?:.*-){%d}.*)(: )(\\d+\\.\\d+)", count, count);
```

And then do what you have to do.

Comment: This works if, as you premised, _there will always be an equal number of dashes in both names_.

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes less is more. I would not even try to push all the logic into the regex. Instead I'd only get one string for the folders:

```
String pattern = "(Comparing )(.*)(: )(\\d+\\.\\d+)";
```

and then have some separate logic to split the folders (using the `-` dashes). This gives you more control (e.g. you can throw an Exception, when there is an odd number of dashes) and would make the program easier to understand.

Regarding the 2nd question:
If this is just a tool, that you use for your own, just go with the single string until it fails.

Otherwise you may just consider to process the input line-by-line: e.g. get a line, apply the regex, split the folder and e.g. write it to another file or somethign.